# C# DateTime ToString("MM-dd-yyyy") returns funny day values

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime-format

I have the following code in the codebehind file of an ASP.Net page

```
txtStartDate.Text = DateTime.Today.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy");
```

Which I expect to return "09-11-2009". However, when I run the page on the development server, I see "09-00-2009" in the text box. I can't see any reason for this, so I'm clearly missing something. Anyone have a clue?

Comment: same thing works fine for me. Maybe your system clock is messed up?

Comment: check it with ToString("MM-ddd-yyyy"); and with ToString("MM-dddd-yyyy"); and see what you get... If you see NO change, then yr format string is not getting to the returned page somehow... If yo see 09-Mon-2009, and 09-Monday-2009, then your computer clock is off

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That [format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) should work as expected.  I'd check your textbox to make sure you don't have some sort of mask (AJAX MaskedEditExtender?) on it.  If you did, and maybe had the mask incorrect, it could overwrite what you were putting in the textbox.

Comment: It's got the AJAX CalendarExtender on it, but the format string for both is identical.

Comment: That was it - I had made an error in copying the format string for the extender.

Answer (score 14):

I can't think why it would show 00, but as a random suggestion you could try:

```
... = DateTime.Today.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this:

```
DateTime.Today.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"))
```

Answer (score 0):

could you check Datetime,Now.ToString() ?

Comment: Yeah, I checked that - same result.

Answer (score 0):

Use .Now to get the local time

```
txtStartDate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy");
```